# How to increase the UICollectionview Cell Size equal to Screen Size in swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, swift4.2

How to increase the `UICollectionView` Cell width & height equal to screen in swift 4.2 ?

Comment: Do you want to change your collectionview cell size to screen size?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your cell size to fit the `collectionview`. Add this in `viewDidLoad`

```
if let flow = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flow.itemSize = self.collectionView.frame.size
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided your `UICollectionViewCell` has a subview of `UIImageView` that is anchored to fill it completely(i.e. UIImageView is anchored UICollectionViewCell in top, bottom, left and right manner).

The following method can be used to size the `UICollectionViewCell` in accordance to the screen screen holding it, this will automatically result in the `UIImageView` being as big as the screen itself.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return self.collectionView.bounds.size  //to ensure that this works as intended set self.collectionView size be the screen size.
        }
```

Please note that the `UICollectionView` is big enough to hold the size of the `UICollectionViewCell` that you seek.

Comment: Although this probably answers the question, is it reasonable for a collection view item to have the parent view size? Wouldn't it be more correct to set it to the bounds size of the collection view? What would happen if the actual collection view gets its size reduced a bit? `return collectionView.bounds.size`

Comment: @AlejandroIván Thanks for bringing that up. What you said would infact, be the correct way to do it. Set the `UICollectionView` to the screen size and then set the `UICollectionViewCell` to the `UICollectionView` size. Going two layers deep with each referring its parents for its size

Comment: Yeah, what I mean is the collection view *item* should not get its size from the parent view, but rather it should be relative to the actual collection view, so it doesn't break when the collection view size changes.